# Problemas con las subtablas en un SQLFORM.smartgrid

Tags: python, web2py

Buenos dias, tengo un problema ...
estoy usando un `SQLFORM.smartgrid` con subtablas asi :

```
def personal():
response.view = 'controll/default.html'
form = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.personal, linked_tables=[
'visitas',
'presupuestos',
],
csv=False,orderby=~db.personal.id)
table-bordered'
return dict(form=form, page_name='Lista de Personal')
```

mi problema es el sgte : 
en la vista de la tabla tabla personal no tengo problemas, pero en sus subtablas me esta dando problemas el `orderby=~db.personal.id`, porque tengo que tenerlo listado del ultimo al primero y me sale el error que muestro en la imagen, si le quito el `orderby=~db.personal.id` funciona y me muestra los datos, que puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]